# How can I include missing dates in the SELECT result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My sales database looks like this

[image: Database]

When I sum and group SELECT...

```
SELECT day, SUM(car) AS cars_sold, SUM(truck) AS trucks_sold,  COUNT(day) AS sales_interactions
FROM sales
WHERE day >= '2024-03-11' AND day <= '2024-03-13' 
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day;
```

The query result from DB

[image: result]

But what I really want as a result is this:

[image: desired result]

I want the date 2024-03-12 (and any other dates in the SELECT date span) to be included with zero values, even if they are missing from the database. Some kind of injection into the result. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use a calendar date table or CTE and LEFT join your sales table. Or, pump up those sales numbers so you sell something every day

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generate_series table function of SQL Server 2022 to have a complete calendar and write a query like :

```
SELECT day, SUM(car) AS cars_sold, SUM(truck) AS trucks_sold,  COUNT(day) AS sales_interactions
FROM   sales
       LEFT OUTER JOIN generate_series(DATEDIFF(day, '2024-03-11' AND day <= '2024-03-13')
          ON day = DATEADD(day, value-1, '2024-03-11')
WHERE  DATEADD(day, value-1, '2024-03-11') BETWEEN '2024-03-11' AND '2024-03-13' 
GROUP BY DATEADD(day, value-1, '2024-03-11')
ORDER BY DATEADD(day, value-1, '2024-03-11');
```